# Online position on QGIS using the INPUT app

Tags: qgis, gps, mergin-maps

I am using QGIS 3.22. I have created a project and loaded into the INPUT app. Is there a way that I can see on my QGIS the current location of the person that is using the INPUT app in the field in real-time?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. For that to work, we would need to implement tracking option (https://github.com/MerginMaps/input/issues/500) and also having auto-sync on.